# An innocent mole riddle

Tags: riddle

It is true I have committed no crime,
yet they shoot me for hundreds of days,
All so they can make me a mole,
without those two right at my end,
then pair me up with my buddy Vee
and release me into the outside world.

Can you tell me what I am?

edit: I tried to delete this because I don't think this is a good riddle because it doesn't rhyme, but I can't (not a complaint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are a

> Movie

yet they shoot me for hundreds of days

> many movies take a while to film (shoot)

All so they can make me a mole, without those two right at my end

> Mo  (mole minus le)

then pair me up with my buddy Vee

> vee (vie)

release me into the outside world.

> When finished, it is released to the world